# How do you declare helper's method in a switch statement

Tags: java, string, boolean, double, helper

In the following code, how do you place the helper's methods into a switch?

I have tried placing my `System.out.println` statements into the switch before declaring the helper's class but it won't work.

What's the easiest way to get the helper's class to start without having to change the code too much?

```
public static void Check(double result){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the 13 digits of the ISBN, seperating each one with the enter key: ");
    String isbn = keyboard.next();
    result = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x < 14; x++) {
    if (x% 2 != 0) {
        double b = Character.getNumericValue(isbn.charAt(x));
        double mul = (b*3);
        result += mul; 
    }
}

public static double method(double[] args) {                                        
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number for X:");
    double x = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double result = 0;
    double number1 = 0;

    do {    
        number1 = (6 * (Math.pow(x,4)) - 13 * (Math.pow(x, 3)) - 18 * (Math.pow(x,2)) + 7 * x + 6) / (24 * (Math.pow(x, 3)) - 39 * (Math.pow(x, 2)) - 36 * x + 7);
        result = (x - number1);
        x = result;
        System.out.println(x);

    } while (Math.abs(number1) >= 0.001);
        System.out.println("the answer is:" + Math.round(result));

    return result;
}

public static boolean formula(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a,b and c with the enter key between");
    double a = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double b = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double c = keyboard.nextDouble();
    double discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    boolean good = false;
    good = (discriminant < 0);

    if (discriminant < 0) {
        System.out.println("No roots :(");
    } else if (discriminant == 0) {
        System.out.println("The single root is : " + ((-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)));
    } else {
        System.out.println("The single root is : " + ((-b + Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)));
        System.out.println("The single root is : " + ((-b - Math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2 * a)));
    }

    return good;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("hi! if you want to do a ISBNnumber checker type: 1. If you want newton's meathod type: 2. If you want to check quadractic formula type: 3.");
    int change = keyboard.nextInt();

    switch (change) {
        case 1: change = 1;

                break;
        case 2: change = 2;
                break;
        case 3: change = 3;
                break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You just call it, like you would any method

Comment: show us the code which is not working

Comment: is there anything i must have in the switch section before i call on it? Are there any requirements for calling on the helper method, can i call it using system.out.print(methodcall);

Comment: As @MadProgrammer said, you can call to method like any other.  In your switch case, why you are assigning value to "change" variable again.  Case matches only when change variable has respective value